# How to get the `"AdjustedRSquared"` from `FittedModel`

Tags: fitting

This my result of model fit:

```
test = {{12.`, 0.2205`, 0}, {24.`, 0.3631`, 0}, {36.`, 0.4696`, 
    0}, {48.`, 0.6112`, 0}, {60.`, 0.7205`, 0}};
fun = NonlinearModelFit[test, k*t^n - d, {n, k}, {t, d}]
```

[image]

We can visualize it

```
 ListPlot[Most /@ test]~Show~Plot[fun["BestFit"] + d, {t, 12, 60}]
```

[image]

So I think the parametre is very good as the visualization.And we can get the proterty `"SinglePredictionErrors"` form the `FittedModel`

```
fun["SinglePredictionErrors"]
```

> {0.0145981, 0.0141301, 0.0134857, 0.0138039, 0.015592}

But how can I get the `"AdjustedRSquared"` from `FittedModel` to measure the result??

[image]

Comment: You may feel [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73197/1871) interesting.

Comment: @xzczd I'm glad to meet you in SE.Your link help me a lot.

Comment: Glad to meet you too, and will be more glad if you link this post back to Tieba to avoid redundant works.

Comment: @xzczd But I think the current answerer have misunderstood this question.

Comment: I don't think so, though not being explicitly claimed, Jim's answer has clearly indicated that, `fun@"AdjustedRSquared"` returns `ComplexInfinity` simply because the `"AdjustedRSquared"` of `fun` is `ComplexInfinity`. Anyway, if you think the answerer has misunderstand you, you can just comment under the answer to further discuss with the answerer rather than sit in silence.

Comment: Moreover, not getting a satisfied answer here isn't a reason for not linking it back to Tieba, or you're waiting for something like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102553/i-was-wondering-how-to-get-the-following-result-using-mathematica-or-any-other-w#comment278496_102553) to happen?

Comment: @yode 永,I'm glad to meet you in SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your model formulation is a bit odd.  All of the dependent variable values are zero which makes the total sum of squares being exactly zero.  And that causes the issues with `fun["AdjustedRSquared"]` not to mention `fun["RSquared"]` and many of the entries in the summary tables.

If you look at the ANOVA table, you'll see that the pieces that go into the estimate of $R^2$ are not what is desired:

```
fun["ANOVATable"]
```

[image: ANOVA table]

Here is the model I think you want to fit:

```
test = {{12.`, 0.2205`}, {24.`, 0.3631`}, {36.`, 0.4696`}, {48.`, 
    0.6112`}, {60.`, 0.7205`}};
fun = NonlinearModelFit[test, k*t^n - d, {n, k, d}, {t}]
fun["AdjustedRSquared"]
(* 0.99948 *)
Show[ListPlot[test], Plot[fun[t], {t, 12, 60}], Frame -> True]
```

[image: Predictions]

However, unless this is just a small sample of your data, attempting to fit 4 parameters (n, k, d, and error variance) with just 5 data points is not going to get you very precise estimates of any of the parameters despite the visual appearance of the fit.

Comment: I'm so sorry for I miss in what is nonlinear regressions.And I think `NonlinearModelFit[test, k*t^n - d, {n, k}, {t}]` is what I want.All the same thanks for you concern this problem.Actually I should delete this foolish question but it's include your response.So I vote it up for your help but have not accept it to be a answer in case of misleading the reader.